# What type is register from react-hook-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-hook-form

When using react-hook-form with Typescript, there is a component that sends some props, `register` being one of them.

The issue is with its type when declared in an interface:

```
export interface MyProps {
  title: string;
  ...
  register: (string | undefined) => void;
}
```

Which is the correct way of declaring `register` here?

Also tried with:

```
import { RegisterOptions } from 'react-hook-form';
    export interface MyProps {
      title: string;
      ...
      register: RegisterOptions;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using react-hook-form version 6 or 7? Because it changed a lot from one version to another.

Comment: According to package.json it is `"react-hook-form": "^7.15.2",`

Comment: just check the docs. The type is on top of the page here https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register

Answer (score 15):

if you are calling register as a prop in a custom component or to use in some custom input field in Typescript, then you can use the below code.

First of all import the UseFormRegister and FieldValues from 'react-hook-form'

```
import {UseFormRegister, FieldValues } from 'react-hook-form'
```

After that, define the type of register as

```
register: UseFormRegister<FieldValues>
```

and boom, you don't need to use 'any' type for register.

Answer (score 8):

Try this.

```
import { RegisterOptions, UseFormRegisterReturn } from 'react-hook-form';

export interface MyProps {
  title: string;
  ...
  register: (name: string, options?: RegisterOptions) => UseFormRegisterReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve register type from `UseFormReturn`.

```
import { UseFormReturn } from 'react-hook-form';

export interface MyProps {
  title: string;
  register: UseFormReturn['register'];
}
```

At react-hook-form, we recommend to forward ref instead of passing `register` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose `forwardRef` or `useFormContext`.

Try this:

```
// Input.tsx
interface InputProps
  extends React.PropsWithRef<JSX.IntrinsicElements['input']> {
  id: string;
  label?: string | ReactElement;
  flex?: boolean;
}

const Input = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>(
  ({ id, label, flex = false, ...rest }, ref) => {
    return (
      <InputWrap flex={flex}>
        {label && (
          <InputLabel flex={flex} htmlFor={id}>
            {label}
          </InputLabel>
        )}
        <InputField id={id} ref={ref} {...rest} />
      </InputWrap>
    );
  },
);

// form.tsx
<Input
    label="password"
    id="password"
    type="password"
    autoComplete="new-password"
    register('password')}
/>
```